# Putting a UITableViewController in a UIPopoverController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

I am trying to create a popover from a `UITableViewController` (EnrollmentPopoverTableViewController) with the code below.

However, I am getting a blank popover.

```
UIViewController *popovercontent = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
UIView * popoverview = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 768)];
EnrollmentPopoverTableViewController *EnrollmentPopoverTable=[[EnrollmentPopoverTableViewController alloc] init];
[popoverview addSubview:EnrollmentPopoverTable.tableView];
popovercontent.view=popoverview;
myPopoverController =[[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:popovercontent];
 UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[self.myPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:cell.bounds inView:cell.contentView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// create the table view controller
EnrollmentPopoverTableViewController *tableViewController =[[EnrollmentPopoverTableViewController alloc] init];

// create a popover using this view controller
myPopoverController =[[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:tableViewController];

// display the view controller from wherever you want to display it
[myPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:sizeOfPopover inView:view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft animated:YES];
```

You're over complicating it.